# Is there a formal definition of Gaps and Islands problems? If so, does this problem satisfy it?

Tags: sql, language-agnostic, relational-database, terminology, gaps-and-islands

It seems that the term "*gaps and islands*" is overused in my workplace. I recently had essentially the following problem given to me under that banner.

> Take a set of data with many rows, each containing lots of data, but in particular, always including a start and stop time column and including many other columns where if one is not NULL then the others are. For example:
>
> | Start Time | Stop Time | Drunkenness | Programming Ability |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | 01 | 60 | 0100 | NULL |
> | 10 | 20 | NULL | 0450 |
> | 40 | 50 | NULL | 0250 |
>
> (you may also use the obvious unpivoted equivalent, but don't worry about that)
>
> and convert that data in to a form where all of the data is collapsed in such a way that you can find out what's true at any given time by only needing to look at the single row that corresponds to that time period. So, for the previous example, you want this:
>
> | Start Time | Stop Time | Drunkenness | Programming Ability |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | 01 | 09 | 0100 | NULL |
> | 10 | 20 | 0100 | 0450 |
> | 21 | 39 | 0100 | NULL |
> | 40 | 50 | 0100 | 0250 |
> | 51 | 60 | 0100 | NULL |
>
> To see that this is what you really want, look at the times in the original rows. Until time 10, only "Dunkenness=0100" is given, so our first row in the result must span from 01 to 09 and contain only Drunkenness info. The next row in the original table spans from 10 to 20, so we must have a row for that time period in the result and it must contain any information that is true at that time (i.e. the "Drunkenness=0100" that is always true and the "Programming Ability = 0450" that is true only between times 10 and 20). As "Programming Ability" is left undefined from time 21 to 39, we must have yet another row where that is NULL. The other two rows are then generated by the same process as the previous rows, so we get the table above.

**Is this really a "*gaps and islands*" problem? Or does the literature give it a different name?** I agree that there are gaps in the first dataset and that the results in the final dataset are split in to islands, but that doesn't seem to be what the literature is referring to when it talk of "*gaps and islands*" problems. The literature seems to care about finding gaps or finding islands, rather than turning gaps in to islands and merging the data like this.

The SQL tag is used because this is a relational database. I am not asking for solutions and I doubt that including an SQL solution in your answer would be enlightening, although they would be welcome. I have therefore not included any SQL code in this question.

I do not believe this question to be opinion-based. I have seen enough coverage of gaps and islands problems to believe that there must be a formal definition of them somewhere. **Answers are highly encouraged to provide a formal definition for these problems and a source for it**. If this in not a gaps and islands problem, but is actually something else, then please give a name and sourced definition for that.

Comment: I think you need to explain the logic by which we get from the input table to the output.  From a long look, this doesn't appear to be a gaps and islands problem.

Comment: I still don't get it, but this doesn't look like gaps and islands.

Comment: Hi - I’m wondering why you care what it’s called? What benefit do you get by applying a label to it?Also, just as an FYI, no-one would design a table like that: where all but one attribute column was always null (assuming a non-trivial number of attributes)

Comment: @NickW There's two benefits: 1) Knowing the name helps me look it up and 2) Knowing that it isn't gaps and islands saves me the time that I'll lose by treating it like it is. As for the table design, that's come up as a consequence of joins rather than something being designed that way.

Comment: Just my opinion obviously but, given that the purpose of this forum is to help people solve problems, wouldn't it be more productive to describe the problem you are facing and ask for help solving it, rather than asking people to classify it? Even if someone does say it is, or isn't, a "gaps and islands" problem, you've no way of knowing if they are correct or not and it gets you no closer to resolving whatever problem it is that you are presumably facing. In fact, if they say it is a "g&i" problem and are wrong then you will waste time searching for non-applicable solutions

Comment: Asking whether this is "gaps & islands" is a different question from what name it might have. What do you actually want to ask? If the former, what is stopping you from finding a definition & evaluating its applicability here? If someone tells you this is a "gaps & islands", what do they mean by that term & what is their justification here, ie how do they say the definition applies, & how are you stuck following it? We can't tell you what they mean. If the latter, what is your own clear description of it? And you know the mapping, so what's to research?--What's the real question?

Comment: Roughly speaking this involves normalizing/canonicalizing intervals/ranges; typical applications involving that are time series & temporal & spatial data/DBs.

Comment: @NickW Hence why I'm asking for a cited definition of Gaps and Islands. It'll be obvious if the problem doesn't match up to the definition that they've given. And if it does match the given definition, then I know where I need to continue my research. As for how that information will help me, refer back to the very start of my question: It's to help me learn whether or not I should listen to my colleagues when they call something "Gaps and Islands".

Comment: @philipxy For the former, I don't trust my skill in finding and reading the correct SQL material. I'm quite new to it. That also explain why I'm asking for a cited definition: So that I know that the person's answer is not just their opinion. For the latter, I'm only asking that because I think it might be handy. I'm really asking because I want to learn whether or not I should listen to my colleagues when they call something "Gaps and Islands".

Comment: Please ask 1 (specific researched non-duplicate) question. [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/3404097) [ask] [Help]

Comment: @philipxy I do not agree that "*By citing a formal definition, show if this is or is not a Gaps and Islands problem. And if it is not so, what is it?*" is more than one question.

Comment: It is some kind of count overlapping intervals problem, at least that is one way to solve the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The condition *if one is not NULL then the others are* means that your rows are just a different representation of key, value pair. In other words, it un-pivoted variant would look like the following

| Key | Value | Start | End |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Drunkenness | 100 | 01 | 60 |
| Programming Ability | 450 | 10 | 20 |
| Programming Ability | 250 | 40 | 50 |

Assume that it passes the data integrity checks, that is, there are no overlapping intervals with different value for the same key. Then it looks like a [type-2 slowly changing dimension](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slowly_changing_dimension#Type_2:_add_new_row) and indeed we can interpret absence of value for *Programming Ability* between 20 and 40 (exclusive) as NULL.

However, one can also interpret that data as *two* separate tables, Drunkenness and Programming Ability merged (via a full join) by start and end date of the intervals.

```
SELECT coalesce(a.start,b.start) as start, coalesce(a.end,b.end) as end,
a.Value, b.Value 
from a full join b on a.start=b.start and a.end = b.end
```

So, for example, b is missing data for (10,60) and you get NULL for Programming Ability in the first row there. You can get your second table if you properly join these two table accounting for time interval overlaps.

```
SELECT greatest(a.start,b.start) as start, least(a.end,b.end) as end,
a.Value, b.Value 
from a full join b on a.start <= b.end and b.start <= a.end
```

Either way, it is not quite Gaps and Islands problem. In that problem, data has some overlapping intervals possibly with gaps and one has to determine non-overlapping intervals of continuity separated by gaps of discontinuity.